# json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Request.consentObtained of type map[string]bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, webapi

I'm trying to call a web Api from Httpclient but got some problem there

```
          HttpResponseMessage results = await (client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v2/verify", KYC));
                var value = results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

In value result

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
> Request.consentObtained of type map[string]bool

is occur..
But From Postman The result is in format of

```
{
"countryCode": "Nepal",
"clientReference": "Test_0001",
"reportingReference": "DZ-3eaca4ae-64bd-4354-89ee-156d206330df",
"matchStatus": "",
"searchErrorMessage": "",
"safeHarbour": false,
"searchStatus": "Successful",
"serviceResponses": {
    "Nepal Government 6": {
        "status": 1,
        "sourceStatus": "Successful",
        "identityVerified": true,
        "verifications": {
            "firstName": true,
            "lastName": true
        },
        "returnedData": {}
    }
}
```

}

Please help me Thank you